# How to keep an element in the same spot while resizing the screen?

Tags: html, css, grid

Is there a way to keep an element in the same spot while resizing the screen without using to many media queries? I already have media queries in the web page but I cant make the element stay in the exact same spot.

```
@media(max-width:550px){ #header{height:150px;} }

@media(max-width: 600px){#nacap{ position:relative; left:200px; top:0px; font-size: 30px;} #header{height:150px; overflow: scroll;} }

@media(min-width: 600px){#nacap {position:relative; left:60px; top:0px; font-size: 30px; } }

@media(min-width: 1000px){ #nacap{ position:relative; left:-65px; top:0px; font-size: 30px; } }
```

Here is a link to the page: https://codepen.io/code7722/pen/PoNZaKR

You can see that when you make the screen smaller, the  element with id nacap moves away and then back from the header image. By the way, the whole header is a grid, maybe that's my problem.

Thank you in advance for your help!!!

Comment: I don't well understand what is your problem. Did your try to set the position with  `absolute` (fix position on the DOM) or `static` (fix position on the window)?

Answer (score 0):

Well first, your media query breakpoints are "awfully programmed". Your breakpoints of

`@media (max-width: 550px)` and `@media (max-width:600px)` can adress the same screen as if the screen has a width of 500px then it fullfills the requirement of both. Same for the min-width queries.
If your screen now is exactly 600px then you have the same problem as it fullfills 2 of the 4 queries. It fullfills to be at least 600px and to be max 600px.

Also your formatting is hard to check and read.

The right formatting should be:

```css
@media only screen
  and(max-width: 550px) { 
    #header {
      height: 150px;
    } 
}

@media only screen
  and (min-width: 551px)
  and (max-width: 600px) {
    #nacap { 
      position: relative; 
      left: 200px; 
      top: 0px; 
      font-size: 30px;
    } 
    #header {
      height: 150px; 
      overflow: scroll;
    } 
}

@media only screen
  and (min-width: 601px)
  and (max-width: 1000px) {
    #nacap {
      position: relative; 
      left: 60px; 
      top: 0px; 
      font-size: 30px; 
    } 
}

@media only screen
  and (min-width: 1001px) { 
    #nacap { 
      position: relative; 
      left: -65px; 
      top: 0px; 
      font-size: 30px; 
    } 
}
```

Then 2nd, a `postion: relative`  with top and left does not work unless you have a parent with `position: absolut`. However if you want to it to be in exactly the same spot, it would be smarter to use `position: fixed`.